# Creating an Expression Tree with !DateTime.HasValue

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a very large expression tree builder that has been built and added to regularly as new functionality was needed. It has been working perfectly for all types including Nullable<> types. Several of my Nullable<> types are DateTime as those columns in my database allow nulls.

Now, I need to adjust the method to be able to filter based on a DateTime having ANY value. In SQL terms:

```
WHERE date_Column IS NOT NULL
```

In LINQ terms:

```
.Where(s => !s.date_column.HasValue)
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to add this to my expression tree. I can add any operator to the MyFilter class that I like, so if a new case will help, that is no problem.

Below is the builder cut down to just the DateTime portion for readability.

```
public class MyFilter
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
}

private Expression<Func<MyDTO, bool>> CreateLambda(MyFilter myFilter)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyDTO), "m");
    Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, myFilter.FieldName);
    Expression target = null;
    Expression exp = null;
    PropertyInfo pi = null;
    MethodInfo mi = null;

    var switchType = property.Type.ToString();

    switch (switchType)
    {
        case "System.DateTime":
            target = (myFilter.FieldValue == "null") ?
                Expression.Constant(null, property.Type) :
                Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDateTime(myFilter.FieldValue));
            switch (myFilter.Operator)
            {
                case "eq":
                    exp = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
                case "ne":
                    exp = Expression.NotEqual(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
                case "ge":
                    exp = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
                case "gt":
                    exp = Expression.GreaterThan(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
                case "le":
                    exp = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
                case "lt":
                    exp = Expression.LessThan(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    Expression<Func<MyDTO, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyDTO, bool>>(exp, parameter);
    return lambda;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to convert `null` to `DateTime` and not `DateTime?` . for all `?` types the name is Nullable1 You are using EF for the queriable right? Your property should be `DateTime?.`

Comment: I think we need more help or types to understand. What/where did `parameter` come from? What is `property`? Why doesn't having `myFilter.FieldValue` == "null" and the `myFilter.Operator` be "ne" work?

Comment: @FilipCordas All objects in C# accept null as a possible value. `DateTime` is no exception.

Comment: @NetMage DateTime is a struct and so is a non-nullable value type the default value is `new Date(1,1,1)`. You can just try to do `DateTime d = null;` so this part `Expression.Convert(target, property.Type)` will create a problem, with null this will work `Expression.Equal(property,target);`

Comment: Ignore the last part the `Expression<Func<DateTime,bool>> exp = (dt) => dt == null;` will actually use convert to 'DateTime?' in the expression tree

Comment: Prior to the switch, I check for the Nullable<DateTime> types and set the switchType to "System.DateTime" so that I end up in the right spot of the switch. Then, everywhere you see "Expression.Convert(target, property.Type)" I am ensuring the types are the same for the methods like "Expression.Equal". Unfortunately, Expression.NotEqual does not work. Just like date_Column != null would not work in SQL. Nullable<DateTime> has a property to check (DateTime.HasValue) which I use in LINQ statements like ".Where(x => x.date_Column.HasValue), but I cannot determine how to add that to the tree.

Comment: @GarlandDuvall Double checked the exp `Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Property(param, "Date"), Expression.Constant(null, typeof(DateTime?)))` get translated to  `IS NOT NULL` if you are using EF(Mabey you are using an old version). Also `Expression.Not(Expression.Property(Expression.Property(param, "Date"), "HasValue"))` transfers to `IS NULL` because of negation at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filip Cordas was correct and both his statements produce the same correct result. I have no idea why `Expression.NotEquals` was not working for me yesterday, but the code above does work as is.

However, since my question was about how to use the HasValue property of a Nullable, I appreciated Filip's second answer very much. Also, now that I see it, it is humbling that I could not get it myself.

The code I implemented to use the HasValue within my environment looks like the following:

```
public class MyFilter
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
}

private Expression<Func<MyDTO, bool>> CreateLambda(MyFilter myFilter)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyDTO), "m");
    Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, myFilter.FieldName);
    Expression target = null;
    Expression exp = null;
    PropertyInfo pi = null;
    MethodInfo mi = null;

    var switchType = property.Type.ToString();

    switch (switchType)
    {
        case "System.DateTime":
            target = (myFilter.FieldValue == "null") ?
                Expression.Constant(null, property.Type) :
                Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDateTime(myFilter.FieldValue));
            switch (myFilter.Operator)
            {
                case "eq":
                    exp = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
                case "ne":
                    if (myFilter.FieldValue == "null")
                    {
                        exp = Expression.Property(property, "HasValue");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exp = Expression.NotEqual(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    }
                    break;
                case "ge":
                    exp = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
                case "gt":
                    exp = Expression.GreaterThan(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
                case "le":
                    exp = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
                case "lt":
                    exp = Expression.LessThan(property, Expression.Convert(target, property.Type));
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    Expression<Func<MyDTO, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyDTO, bool>>(exp, parameter);
    return lambda;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help